# How to join two arrays in a map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

What I want is to join my arrays that I get from my map function.

I tried to do with `reduce` :

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
    values.fields.map((el, idx) => {           
      
      console.log({ ...el, index: idx }); // this `console.log` prints me one array after the other
    }).reduce((acc, x) => {console.log(acc,x)}); // I tried with `reduce` but it prints me null
```

Also tried to do with `useState`:

```
 const onFinish = (values) => {
    values.fields.map((el, idx) => {           
      if (myArray === null){
        setMyArray(() => {
          return { ...el, index: idx };
        });
      }
      else {
        setMyArray(() => {
           return {...myArray,...el, index: idx };
        });
      }
    });
      console.log(myArray) // at my first call to this const onFinish myArray is printed as [] and at the second it prints with the last object only
   };
```

Someone knows how to get these objects `joined/merged` ?

Sample data the way that it's print:
[image]

How I want to be: [image]

Comment: Post some sample data and what you want the result to be

Comment: It looks like `myArray` isn't an array (?)

Comment: @James it's an object , but i want to join there objects to show an array

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I edited it , thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altghough it is still not very clear from the screenshots (*always prefer to use text and not images for data/code*), it looks like you want

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
  const updatedValues = values.fields.map((field, index) => ({...field, index}));
  console.log( updatedValues );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
  if (myArray === null){
    setMyArray(() => {
      return [{ ...el, index: idx }];
    });
  }
  else {
    setMyArray(() => {
       return [...myArray, {...el, index: idx }];
    });
  }
```